# Use Umbraco content macro in a page template

Tags: umbraco

I'm looking to re-use an Umbraco Macro that's been rendered within a content pane, and use it in a page template. The block on the content page is below, what would I have to do to turn this into a new macro for a page template?

```
<div umb_source="5766" umb_firsttab="5846" 
    umb_macroalias="widgetname" 
    umb_secondtab="5847" 
    ismacro="true" onresizestart="return false;" 
    umbversionid="b8fc56a2-f4b0-42ee-a3b8-7115acdff669" 
    umbpageid="5756" 
    title="This is rendered content from macro" 
    class="umbMacroHolder">
    <!-- startUmbMacro -->
    <span>This macro does not provides rendering in WYSIWYG editor
    </span>
<!-- endUmbMacro --></div>
```

Comment: What version of Umbraco are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using the "Insert Macro" button in the template editor (in the Settings section) to add the template. It gives you an interface to choose the appropriate options that will build the macro tag for you.

But something like this should work (Simular to Ankur Ghelani's, but includes the other options):

```
<umbraco:marco alias="widgetname" runat="server"
    source="5766"
    firsttab="5846"
    secondtab="5847" />
```

Comment: Thanks Douglas, this managed to pull some of the right content through and gave me the clue I needed to work on it further. Seems that untangling other peoples work in Umbraco is hugely unintuitive. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In **template** you use as following:

```
<umbraco:Macro Alias="widgetname" runat="server" />
```

It should work

Comment: I tried this in the first instance, and again after you suggested it. It doesn't work.

Comment: did you make sure `alias` name of macro? if you are trying to insert macro from `Umbraco CMS` you will find inside `Template` third option from "icon menu", you can try and use that option in insert `Macro` or check your `Macro`

Comment: Yeah, checked the Alias name, I also added source="****" and this also didn't work.

Comment: do you have any property like Macro Public property, is it depend on that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: if you see in to Developer section Macro and go to the Parameters tab and you will find parameter do you have any parameters then you have to specify in Macro.

Comment: Parameters are 'source' and the 'type' is 'contentPicker'. For reference, I've inherited an Umbraco build, and none of the original team are left to confer with.